# Centering window in canvas with Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to make a word processor like MS Word in Tkinter. I struggled for a couple days to make  a scrollbar that actually worked, but the only solution I found involved creating a new window inside a frame inside a canvas. The code looks like this:

```
from tkinter import *


class GUI:

    def __init__(self, master):
        #Creating window
        self.master = master
        master.title('Text Editor')
        w = master.winfo_screenwidth()
        h = master.winfo_screenheight()
        self.master.geometry("%dx%d"%(w, h))

        self.frame = Frame(master)
        self.frame.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=1)
        self.frame.pack_propagate(False)

        #Creating canvas
        self.canvas = Canvas(self.frame, background='lightgrey')
        self.canvas.pack(side=LEFT, fill=BOTH, expand=1)
        #Creating scrollbar
        self.scroll = Scrollbar(self.frame, orient=VERTICAL, command=self.canvas.yview)
        self.scroll.pack(side=RIGHT, fill=Y)

        #Configuring Scrollbar
        self.canvas.configure(yscrollcommand=self.scroll.set)
        self.canvas.bind('<Configure>', lambda e:     self.canvas.configure(scrollregion=self.canvas.bbox('all')))

        #Second frame for scroll region
        in_frame = Frame(self.canvas, background='lightgrey')

        #Create window inside inner frame
        self.canvas.create_window((0, 0), window=in_frame, anchor=NW)

        #textbox
        self.textframe = Frame(in_frame, width='8.5i', height='11.0i')
        self.textframe.pack(pady=(30, 20))
        self.textframe.pack_propagate(False)
        self.text = Text(self.textframe)
        self.text.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=1)

master = Tk()
GUI(master)
master.mainloop()
```

This code allows me to use the scrollbar, however it moves the text box all the way to the left of the screen like this:
[App with text on wrong side](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xutlt.png)

when it should look like this (this is how it looked before creating the new window for the scrollbar to work):

[App with text editor on right side](https://i.stack.imgur.com/POndZ.png)

I tried just making the scrollbar work with the canvas (no new wondow) but it won't work. Also, I tried setting the anchor of the new window to CENTER instead of NW.
I just want to have the centered view with a scrollbar.

Thank you!!

Comment: why are you using a frame inside of a canvas? Why do you need to put a text widget inside a frame inside a canvas? The text widget itself is scrollable. Why add the extra layers?

Comment: The first frame (inner_frame) I added it to scroll the area per a tutorial that I saw on how to scroll the entire app. Now, the frame for the text (textframe) I made because I wanted the text box to have a specific size (8.5ix11.0i). I read that you can't set a fixed text box size as it changes according to the font. The idea is to have the text box fill the frame so it remains constant no matter the font size. Also, the idea is not to scroll the text box but the entire window since the text box is larger than the window height

Answer (score 0):

If you want to center the text box, you can set the width of `in_frame` the same as the width of the canvas.  It is normally set when the canvas is resized:

```py
...
#Second frame for scroll region
in_frame = Frame(self.canvas, background='lightgrey')
#Create window inside inner frame with tag "in_frame"
self.canvas.create_window((0, 0), window=in_frame, anchor=NW, tags="in_frame")

# normally update scrollregion when the inner frame is resized, not the canvas
in_frame.bind('<Configure>', lambda e: self.canvas.configure(scrollregion=self.canvas.bbox('all')))
# set the width of the inner frame when the canvas is resized
self.canvas.bind('<Configure>', lambda e: self.canvas.itemconfigure("in_frame", width=e.width))
...
```

Note that the `scrollregion` should be updated when the inner frame `in_frame` is resized, not the canvas.